# Azure Synapse Serverless - SQL query to return rows in directory for each file

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I have an Azure Data Lake Gen2 Container in which I have several json files. I would like to write a query that returns a record for each file. I am not interested in parsing the files, I just want to know what files are there and have this returned in a view. Does anyone have any tips on how I might do this? Everything I have found is about how to parse/read the files...I am going to let Power BI do that since the json format is not standard. In this case I just need a listing of files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filepath()` and `filename()` function in Azure Synapse Analytics serverless SQL pools to return those.  You can even `GROUP BY` them to return aggregated results.  A simple example:

```
SELECT 
    [result].filepath() AS filepath,
    [result].filename() AS filename,
    COUNT(*) AS records
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://azureopendatastorage.blob.core.windows.net/nyctlc/yellow/puYear=2019/puMonth=4/*.parquet',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
GROUP BY [result].filepath(), [result].filename()
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-specific-files#:%7E:text=The%20filepath%20function%20returns%20a,returns%20path%20relative%20to%20DATA_SOURCE.) for further examples.